# Seeking tools to convert ways of osm data to format including coordinates?

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations

I have asked [Getting coordinates of ways in *.pbf file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202653) for getting coordinates of way data in osm. In detail, the ways including some kinds of amenities and tourist attractions of whole Japan. So the volume is very large (That is one of the reasons why I do not choose to use Overpass API). If using the code

```
osmosis.bat --read-pbf JP.pbf --tf accept-ways tourism=* --tf reject-relations --used-node  --write-xml de-pipeline.osm
```

The output did include the coordinates but it is like this:

```
<node id="1" lat="" lon=""/>
<node id="2" lat="" lon=""/>
<way id="1">
 <nd ref="1"/>
 <nd ref="2"/>
</way>
```

And if I want to get the coordinates of a way I need to 
traverse the entire document which I think will take a lot of time if the file is large. So I am wondering whether there are some tools to directly get each way as an element(object) that includes the node coordinates like this (or any other formats that do not need to traverse the file again):

```
<way id="1">
 <node id="1" lat="" lon=""/>
 <node id="2" lat="" lon=""/>
</way>
```

Comment: You're going to need to traverse the file if you want all the elements that match some criteria. You could choose to import it into a database (postgis is popular, spatialite might be useful, or you can also do your own Overpass server http://dev.overpass-api.de/), or you could just use http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API directly. What are you going to do with the data when you've extracted it?

Comment: @BradHards Thanks for your information. In fact, the data volume is rather large and so traversing them all or loading them to the database may be not suitable for me, if there are no tools that do not have to use API, I will traverse them.

Comment: Overpass server has the entire planet loaded. Its well within most reasonable desktop (or low end server) capability. You still haven't explained the purpose you are aiming at is, which makes it hard to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I just want to extract some kinds of amenities and tourist attractions all over Japan (with the pbf file size 1.2GB ). Since the data volume is large and I am not sure how to filter data by country boundaries in overpass (also it is slow to use API), I prefer to use pbf file instead..

Comment: You probably should put that in the question.

Comment: You mentioned 'it is slow to use API'. Can you post an overpass turbo shortlink of your Overpass query? Maybe your query was just not as good as it could be. Did you use `out geom;` to get the output format similar to what you described above?

Comment: Thank you for your information. `out geom` really helps! But if I want to filter all the data in Japan, what kind of spatial filter should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have extracted the data of interest locally, you can transform it to any other supported format using GDAL ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f gml de-pipeline.gml de-pipeline.osm

ogr2ogr -f CSV -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT  de-pipeline.csv de-pipeline.osm
```

See also [Lossless conversion from shapefiles to XML/JSON/Text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121182/lossless-conversion-from-shapefiles-to-xml-json-text)

Answer (score 0):

After my experiment, I found that using API is faster than iterating the whole file. So I am now using API to solve this problem.